# Passing an array to a method in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, parameters

I have a problem with this code. When I call the method sort and pass an array as a parameter to it (sort(array)), it is giving me an error. Can someone please tell what is wrong?  Thanks

```
public class MergeSort {

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort (T[] a) {
    if (a.length <= 1) 
        return;

    int hSize = a.length / 2;

    T[] lTab = (T[])new Comparable[hSize];
    T[] rTab = (T[])new Comparable[a.length-hSize];

    System.arraycopy(a, 0, lTab, 0, hSize);
    System.arraycopy(a, hSize, rTab, 0,a.length-hSize);

    sort(lTab); 
    sort(rTab);
    merge(a, lTab, rTab);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge (T[] a, T[] l, T[] r) {
    int i = 0;  // indexes l
    int j = 0;  // indexes r
    int k = 0;  // indexes a

    while (i < l.length && j < r.length)
        if (l[i].compareTo(r[j]) < 0)
            a[k++] = l[i++];
        else
            a[k++] = r[j++];

    while (i < l.length) 
        a[k++] = l[i++];

    while (j < r.length) 
        a[k++] = r[j++];
    }

}
```

The error is:

`method sort in class MergeSort cannot be applied to given types Required T[] Found int[]`

Comment: which error is displayed?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: 404 - Error not Found

Comment: the error is this:

method sort in class MergeSort cannot be applied to given types
Required T[]
Found int[]

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure the `type` provided indeed `implements Comparable`

It seems you are passing `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`

You will not be able to use primitive types. For those cases, you will have to use their `Wrappers` which inherently implement Comparable.

If you are using your own `type` (i.e. your own Object) then that type `must` implement Comparable.

Comment: Exactly this!  If you call your method with an array of primitive int you will actually get a compilation error.

Comment: Instead of public class MergeSort, I wrote public class MergeSort extends Comparable but it gave me another error ("no interface expected here")

Comment: You can't extend a method declaration. The `type` you pass is what needs to extend Comparable. For example if you pass a `String[]` it will work because `String` inherently extends Comparable... If you are passing a primitive type, then you must use the Wrapper object (instead of `int[]` use `Integer[]` which also extends Comparable)